# Unable to use backslash `\` in Golang os.Arg variable

Tags: go, command-line-arguments

I have made a program in Golang and I am trying to use a file as the first argument when launching my program.

*For example: `./goprogram.exe C:\Acidic\image.png`*

When my program tries to use the os.Arg[1] variable which should be the link to the image.png file, it returns the string without any of the backslashes (C:Acidicimage.png).

How can I use the whole string of an argument without characters being escaped?

I have made a little example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) >= 2 {
        fmt.Println(os.Args[1])
    }
}
```

I run `go run args.go C:\Users\image.png` and it outputs `C:Usersimage.png`

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/nTwHekk.png Go1.6x64 Win10x64

Comment: http://imgur.com/VwHquPW go1.6.3 windows/amd64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be your shell. Try quoting the file path:

```
./goprogram.exe 'C:\Acidic\image.png' # prevents escape sequence execution
```

A string fo type `C:\Acidic\image.png` (with single `\`'s) is not a valid string in Go (invalid escape sequence `\A`, etc) and would not even compile.

Comment: Ah yes that worked. The only problem though is that I am trying to use my program with Windows' "open with" and that one is not using quotations for the argument.

Comment: You can try modifying your executable's target. Try adding quotes there. Note that you might have to create a shortcut before you can modify the `exe`'s `target`.

Comment: I understand if that's the only option :/ but it would be good if there was a way to solve this from within the program.

Comment: Add the `windows` tag to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Put any argument between quotes:

```
./goprogram.exe "C:\Acidic\image.png"
```

Comment: Ah yes that worked. The only problem though is that I am trying to use my program with Windows' "open with" and that one is not using quotations for the argument.